# Isolating a variable that appears in the addend and exponent

Tags: exponential-function

I am trying to rearrange the following equation containing variables 'y' and 'z' in terms of 'z = ...'

'a', 'b', and 'c' are known constants.

The equation is as follows:

$$ y = \frac{z + b(e^{-cz}-1)}{a} $$

My problem is that 'z' appears in both the addend and the exponent.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Voted up for your extremely correct and descriptive title.  Unfortunately, there isn't an elementary solution to the equation in general.  See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=solve+y+%3D+(z%2B(e%5E(-c+z)+-1+)%2Fa+for+z